# Quotes on Srimad Bhagavat Purana

Tags: bhagavata-purana

I am looking for quotes of dignitaries on Srimad Bhagavatam. Quotes on usefulness, importance etc.  I tried hard to search for it on the internet with no success. I hope you can help me.

Comment: The name of the Bhagavatam is mentioned and celebrated as the best and most important of all the Puranas in several Puranas. See related: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8790/why-bhagavata-purana-is-considered-the-foremost-of-all-puranas

Answer (score 1):

I am providing the opinion of Sri Chaitanyadev on Srimad-Bhagavatam.As per Sri Sri Chaitanya-Charitamrita(2/25/78-84), He says:

> The meaning of Pranava and Gayatri are the same. That meaning is explained in the four slokas by God to Brahmaa. Brahmaa advised the same to Narada.Narada communicated the same to Byasadeva. Byasadeva found it to be an explanation of the Brahma-Sutras composed by Him. So He decided to write Srimad-Bhagavatam as the commentary of His Brahma-Sutras. Therefore **the essence of the Vedas and the Upanishads is provided in Srimad-Bhagavatam.**

Quoting fom different scriptures, His direct disciple Sripada Jiva Goswami writes in his Tattva-Sandarva(53/21):

> **Vyasadeva was not satisfied after compiling the scriptures including the puranas.He perceived Srimad-Bhagavatam in the samadhi state, which is a unique commentary of His Brahma-Sutras. So Srimad-Bhagavatam is the essence of all the scriptures.**

According to Swami Vivekananda

> **The love of Gopis [described in Srimad-Bhagavatam] is so pure that none can understand it without renouncing the world.Its impossible to understand with with even an iota of impurities like lust and greed and desire for fame. the main objective of the incarnation of Sri Krishna is to preach this love of the gopis. Even Gita, which is the pinnacle of all the philosophical scriptures looks dwarf beside this love.**(Ref: Quotation in M-kar Baba, Sitaramdas Omkarnath,Mahamilan Math,page 24)

Comment: Do you happen to have any contemporary quotes?

Answer (score 0):

Satya Sai Baba talks about Bhagavatam as follows

http://www.vahini.org/Discourses/d7-bhagavatam.html

Question 100

> Bhâgavatha is a huge tree. Lord Nârâyana is verily the seed of this
>   tree. Brahmâ is the plant (that emerges from the seed as a sprout,
>   sapling, a plant and then into a tree). Nârada is the trunk. Sage
>   Vyâsa is the branches. The sacred story of Krishna is the fruit,
>   filled with sweet juice.

Answer (score 0):

Sanatana Gosvami glorifies Srimad Bhagavatam in Sri Krishna lila Stava

> sarva-śāstrābdhi-pīyūṣa sarva-vedaika-sat-phala |
>   sarva-siddhānta-ratnāḍhya sarva-lokaika-dṛk-prada ||
>
> O nectar churned from the ocean of all the scriptures! O unique,
>   preeminent fruit of the Vedas! O you who are richly endowed with the
>   jewels of all philosophical conclusions! O sole bestower of vision to
>   everyone!
>
> sarva-bhāgavata-prāṇa śrīmad-bhāgavata prabho | kali-dhvāntoditāditya
>   śrī-kṛṣṇa-parivartita ||
>
> O life force of all the topmost Vaiṣṇavas! O Śrīmad Bhāgavatam! O
>   Almighty! O sun arisen to dispel the darkness of the Age of Kali! O
>   You who caused many to return to Śrī Kṛṣṇa!
>
> paramānanda-pāṭhāya prema-varṣy-akṣarāya te | sarvadā sarva-sevyāya
>   śrī-kṛṣṇāya namo ’stu me ||
>
> Reciting you gives the highest bliss: Your syllables rain pure love.
>   You should always be served by everyone. I offer obeisances to you,
>   Śrī Kṛṣṇa.
>
> mad-eka-bandho mat-saṅgin mad-guro man-mahā-dhana | man-nistāraka
>   mad-bhāgya mad-ānanda namo ’stu te ||
>
> O my foremost friend, my companion, my teacher, my great wealth, my
>   deliverer, my good fortune, my bliss! I offer my respects to you.
>
> asādhu-sādhutā-dāyinn atinīcoccatā-kara | hā na muñca kadācin māṁ
>   premṇā hṛt-kaṇṭhayoḥ sphura ||
>
> O giver of saintliness to unsaintly people! O uplifter of very lowly
>   persons! Ah, don’t ever leave me, and kindly manifest as pure love in
>   my heart and throat.

Hemādri in Mukhā-phala says:

> vedāḥ purāṇaṁ kāvyaṁ ca prabhur mitraṁ priyeva ca | bodhayantīti hi
>   prāhus trivṛd bhāgavataṁ punaḥ ||
>
> The Vedas, Purāṇas and poetic works instruct one like the master, friend and lover respectively. However Bhāgavatam teaches in all three ways.